# declaring an STL container to store a variable of a template type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a class which has a member `args` which stores a `std::string` and a `std::type_index`.

A template function `setArgument()` adds the name of an attribute and its `typeid` to `args`.

```
class OperationEntry:
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index>> args;

    template <class AttrType>
    inline OperationEntry& setArgument(const std::string& name)
    {
        args_.push_back({name, typeid(AttrType)});
        return *this;

    }
```

I want to extend the definition of `args` to be an `std::tuple` and hold an additional value which will be populated in `setArgument()`. However the type of the
value is the template type `AttrType`.

My question is how do I declare `args` to store this template type as I don't know in advance the type' ?

for example - `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, AttrType>> args;`

for example `setArgument()` could add

```
"alpha", f, 3.3
"beta", i, 3
```

Comment: Look up `std::any`.

Comment: You can't "store a type". Types are not objects. What do you want to use the type for?

Comment: @StoryTeller I've updated my question with an example and fixed a typo. I don't know how to declare the type of the 3rd element in `std::tuple` to be the type that `setargument()` is instantiated with.

Comment: I'm using c++ 11 mainly and some c++ 14.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a vector have to have a specific type, so you need *some kind* of type-erasure.

If the types that `setArgument` can be instantiated with are truely unconstrained, you want an `any` type. [`boost::any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/any.html) is C++11 compatible, and can be replaced by [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) when you move to C++17.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index, boost::any>> args;
```

If there are a finite list of types to choose from, you can instead use `variant` ([`boost::`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html) before C++17, [`std::`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) afterward).

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::type_index, boost::variant<int, float, string/*, ...*/>>> args;
```